# echo shell_exec("echo %USERPROFILE%") does not return the right value

Tags: php, environment-variables, shell-exec

I am trying to get the user profile path on windows from php shell_exec and echo %USERPROFILE%.

The dos command by itself works fine:

```
C:\>echo %USERPROFILE%
C:\Users\username
```

but from php it just returns '%USERPROFILE%':

```
echo shell_exec("echo %USERPROFILE%");
```

I also tried with getenv('USERPROFILE'); but I get nothing returned, even after changing the phi.ini variables_order to "EGPCS"

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> C:\Users\temp_000>php -r "var_dump(getenv('USERPROFILE'));"
> string(17) "C:\Users\temp_000"
>
> C:\Users\temp_000>php -r "var_dump($_ENV['USERPROFILE']);"
> string(17) "C:\Users\temp_000"
>
> C:\Users\temp_000>php
> <?php
> var_dump(shell_exec("echo %USERPROFILE%"));
> ^Z
> string(18) "C:\Users\temp_000
> "
> ```

All work for me. Only thing I can think of is that you're running your PHP scripts on Linux, but you said you're on Windows, so... not really sure. Anyway, just wanted to show the result of my testing.

Comment: Thanks, yeah not sure what the problem is, maybe some other php.ini config I have.